# How do you see the STDOUT of a child process in the calling parent process in csh script

Tags: unix, scripting, ssh, csh

I am calling a csh script that the first thing it does is starts a new group.

I need to be able to see the standard output from the child process that is executed after the fork. I also want the parent  process to 'hang' unitl the  child process is finished.

Here is the script (`razor_from_cgwin.sh`).

(sort of)

```
newgrp name
source /stuff/morestuff/stuffiwant
razor -c thread -f Keil1403 -g lib . -o
chmod +x *
./rz_build*
> server{me}:./razor_from_cgwin.sh
> server{me}:
```

What I want is this:

```
>server{me}:./razor_from_cgwin
>(hang)
>any output from child forked process
>server{me}:
```

Razor is the CM I am using on the project I am working on.
It is not important to this problem except that i need to start a new group to call it.
I am calling the script  (`./razor_from_cgwin.sh`) from a ssh session from CYGWIN :)

Comment: which particular sub-command's output are you trying to see?  p.s. you can indent four spaces to turn that listing into "code" style

Comment: p.p.s. please edit any notes into the original question or as comments, not full replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems odd - if this was a Unix system there's no reason I can think of why you wouldn't automatically see the output from the child process.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The original problem was that I was forking a sub prcoess in the script.

Now  that I use "Here Documents". I see the output in my calling console. So Alnitak was correct.